# How to format a number in a typescript string interpolation?

Tags: javascript, typescript, format

I've an angular pipe that should do some basic transformation to display a distance in kilometers if the distance is bigger than a given amount.

```
export class DistancePipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: number, ...args: unknown[]): unknown {
    if(value>1000){
      return `${(value/1000):d2} km`;//<--- This won't compile
    }else{
      return `${value} m`;
    }
  }

}
```

But I'm struggling to display the distance in kilometers.

The goal would be to have the following behavior:

```
1141 -> 1.1
501 -> 501
1011 -> 1
2091 -> 2.1
1990 -> 2
999-> 999
```

I tried to use `ToFixed`, but it will enforce to display the `0` of `1.0`, which is not acceptable in my case. This seems crazy that I can't do such a simple thing as a format

Comment: Try `toFixed(1).replace('.0','')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An extra conversion to `Number` removes `.0`. Btw 1151/1000 would imho (rounded) be 1.2, not 1.1.

```js
const formatNr = nr => nr > 1000 ? +((nr/1000).toFixed(1)) : nr;
//                                 ∟ here
const numbers = [1151, 501, 1011, 2091, 1990, 999]; 
console.log(numbers.map(nr => `${nr} -> ${formatNr(nr)}`));
```

Comment: You're totally right about the 1151, sorry. I guess it does the trick even doing a string to make a number to make a string make no sense to me.